# How to load div like iframe with a url with parameters(Load external data to a cell)

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I would like to show a status in field but the result data is from an external link which means another sharepoint list.
I'm using something similar below but not sure if this is the best way to do it.

```
   <td>
    <iframe src="/sites/showCommsStatus.aspx?id={@ID}&amp;user={$loginUser}" width="20px" height="25px"></iframe>
    </td>
```

As you can see i'm passing the ID and the login users name.
How can i do this smarter maybe using jquery and a div?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe use JQuery.Ajax call to get the data and fill in the div but that'll still require you to send the id and name.

Comment: @naijacoder- you got the answer you want ..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make Ajax call using `.ajax()` and than load the page data in your div using `.html()` method of the javascript

you can read about ajax call over here : [Jquery Ajax Calling functions](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/07/jquery-ajax-calling-functions.html)

Comment: Pranay can you update the link with the download.Can't download the code.Update the rar file
Chrs

Comment: @naijacoder - you can download code from here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/Jquery_Ajax_Calling.aspx